# Passing Java arguments to the Jetty Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jetty, java-17, maven-jetty-plugin

I am trying to add support to Java 17 for a project that also supports Java 8 and Java 11. It uses the Maven Jetty plugin for deployments. When running jetty:run I get the following error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.lang.Object.finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to an unnamed module
```

I was able to deploy the project without errors by manually adding the `--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED` Java argument using IntelliJ IDEA. It generated a command similar to this.

```
java --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED  jetty:run
```

Is there a way to pass the argument using the POM.xml without having to manually set the Java argument? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

### Version numbers:

- Java: 17
- Jetty Maven plugin: 9.4.35.v20201120
- Maven: 3.11.0

Here is the pom file I am working on: https://github.com/openmrs/openmrs-core/blob/458f9417c1d2ab45c37fbdac8b94ec3a854cb7be/webapp/pom.xml#L100-L129

Answer (score 2):

> `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.lang.Object.finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to an unnamed module`

You really need to fix your code.

`Object.finalize()` has been deprecated since JDK 9, and will likely not work as you expect in a future JVM.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()

Either your code, or one of your dependencies is relying on a feature that is deprecated.  (Eg: powermock for the longest time relied on Object.finalize, but was forced to updated their codebase once JDK 16 hit and illegal-access became deny by default on the JVM)

THIS is the proper way to fix this specific issue.

---

Back to how to make your project limp along on JDK 17 within Jetty ...

Jetty 9.x is now at End of Community Support.

See: https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/7958

Jetty 9 does NOT support JPMS use on jetty-maven-plugin.

That was first added in Jetty 10, in a fork mode.

See the plugin configuration options `deployMode` (in `FORK` mode) and `jvmArgs` (only available during fork mode)

https://eclipse.dev/jetty/documentation/jetty-10/programming-guide/index.html#deployment-modes

In short, you will either use a proper `<configuration>` section in your jetty-maven-plugin to specify those options, or use the `<properties>` section to define the property equivalents of those 2 configurations. (`jetty.deployMode` and `jetty.jvmArgs` respectively)

```xml
<properties>
  <jetty.deployMode>FORK</jetty.deployMode>
  <jetty.jvmArgs>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</jetty.jvmArgs>
</properties>

<plugin>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.ee8</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-ee8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>12.0.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>run-jetty</id>
      <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <deployMode>${jetty.deployMode}</deployMode>
        <contextXml>${basedir}/src/main/jetty/jetty-context.xml</contextXml>
        <jettyXmls>
          <jettyXml>${basedir}/src/main/jetty/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
        </jettyXmls>
        <stopPort>9898</stopPort>
        <stopKey>DEADBEEF</stopKey>
        <jvmArgs>${jetty.jvmArgs}</jvmArgs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

The reason for defining both in a `<configuration>` and a `<properties>` is so that you can use any of the other jetty-maven-plugin goals on the command line without defining another `<execution>` or `<configuration>` section. (it also helps with IT testing)